# A word/phrase meaning the "house where I was born"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

For instance, to refer to the place you were born you say "my hometown." How about when referring to the house where you were born? I thought of "my parents' house", but I think it'll sound strange if one of the parents no longer lives there?

Comment: Sure, why not? I hope we're going to get some royalties from your book, or at least an acknowledgement. I agree, this isn't really about English, it's about writing.

Comment: How about now? I rephrased the question.

Comment: FWIW, the place you were born is your *birthplace*. It is not necessarily your *hometown*. The latter is the town where you grew up or where you have your principal residence.

Comment: And I would hazard that most people are not actually born in their homes, although some few are.  I don't actually have a home where I was born. I do have a birthplace, and a childhood home though.

Comment: I'm confused. You are looking for a word that means the house you were born in OR the first house you lived in (after being born somewhere) OR the very first house you grew up in OR a house you grew up in? Would this exclude the house if it wasn't your parents' house? (Maybe they died or went to prison!) Which is it?

Comment: FWIW: You could certainly coin the term *birth house*. I think most readers would understand that instantly, and they would understand that you were born in a house (not, e.g., in a hospital), which is uncommon in many countries. (However, that term does not necessarily convey the fact that the house was where you or your parents lived.)

Comment: alma mater = nurturing mother; alma domus = nurturing home/house; natus domus = birth home/house.

Comment: "[Birthhouse](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ME4HVNuFEIKN8QfbroCoBg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22birthhouse%22&safe=off&start=10&tbm=bks)" is used in literature.

Comment: How about *nest*? It'd be a colloquial usage, but I think it would be understood well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Birthplace](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Birthplace): was used to indicate the place where someone was born especially in the past. Nowadays is it more common to be born in the birth-centre of an  hospital and birthplace  usually refers to the village/town where someone is born.

Birthplace:

> - The place where someone is born.

John Quincy Adams [Birthplace](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Quincy_Adams_Birthplace):

> - **The John Quincy Adams Birthplace is a historic house** at 141 Franklin Street in Quincy, Massachusetts. It is the saltbox home in which the sixth United States President, John Quincy Adams, was born in 1767 to Abigail Adams and John Adams.

A common  expression to indicate your home is **the house where you grew up** referring specifically to the first years or the first part of your life.

Source: www.wikipedia.org

Comment: How funny, my neck of the woods. Birthplace can refer to a building or place where a person is born. Place of birth is often seen on official forms, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the home where you were born and lived as a child your *childhood home*. This doesn't preclude being born in a hospital. Nowadays, newborns stay only one or two days in a hospital before being taken home by their parents

> ### Johnny Cash's childhood home opens to the public
>
> Country music legend Johnny Cash's childhood home has been opened to
>   the public as part of a drive to revitalise the Arkansas town where he
>   grew up.
>
> The Cash family moved to the house in Dyess in 1935, when Johnny was
>   three, as part of a government drive to help families after the Great
>   Depression.

source: http://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-28827883

**EDIT**
If the *childhood home* is not the same home where one was born then the OP needs to specify more clearly. I would suggest the following phrase:

> The home where I was born

Comment: Remove *were born and* from your answer and it will be OK. Nothing in *childhood home* implies or even suggests that the child was born there. And in fact your citation says that J. Cash moved to his childhood home when he was 3, suggesting (but not stating) that he was not born there.

Comment: The OP is asking for the home where a person is born and lived with his parents. Childhood home answers *his* question. The excerpt *also* illustrates the fact that you can call the house where you lived as a child a childhood home regardless if you were "born" there. I think the OP is smart enough to figure it out for himself. :)

Comment: Uh, no one is questioning the intelligence of the OP. *Childhood home* does not in **any sense** mean, imply, or even suggest the house a person was born in. Sorry, but it just doesn't. Your excerpt does not illustrate "*also*" what you say it does; it illustrates **only** that. Anyway, it is of course fine with me if you want to keep your answer as it is. I was only trying to help. Without the extra claim about birth place, what you say would be correct. (But it would not answer the question, which is explicitly about birth place.)

Comment: @drew *"not in *any* sense..."* well allow me to disagree, the term *childhood home* does imply it is a home where one grew up, not necessarily it *has to be* the same home where one was conceived or was given birth to, but that's just being persnickety. But I shall add an edit to clarify. (*moans* Can I never give a few simple lines as an answer on this site?)

Comment: If you disagree that it is incorrect, then by all means, keep your statement that *childhood home* means the "*home where you were born*". Please don't change your answer on my account. And my correction was not being persnickety. I made the same point wrt *hometown* in my comment to the question. *Childhood home*, like *hometown*, does not speak about place of birth.

Comment: One or two days? In my experience, in the UK at least, usually only a few hours. An overnight stay in hospital is only warranted if there was some particular complication which requires the mother or baby to stay in for observation.

Comment: @tobyink blimey, it's got worse then! Not even one night? Thirty years ago in Italy it was between three to six days. I knew hospital stays were shorter in the UK, but not as short as a couple of hours.

Comment: Worse? Better! This is generally seen as a victory against the increasing medicalization of childbirth. Until about 60 years ago, it was rare to go to hospital to give birth; not even especially common for doctors to be involved at all. Post-war, birth became increasingly medical, but that trend is reversing.

Comment: @tobyink  Don't tell me. Let me guess, you've never given birth to a baby. When that day arrives, you'll want to rest for at least one day. In any case, I am tired of having people nit-picking, this isn't aimed directly at you btw. But, I'm deleting this post.

Comment: Very few people in Western countries are born at  home. Most are born in hospitals or clinics. Being born at home is quite unusual. Childhood home generally is just the place one was raised or grew up.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, you can use the words ***birthhouse*** and ***birthhome***.

There aren't any dictionary entries for these words but they are mainly used in literature, so we can consider these words as neologisms. *Birthhouse* is more common than *birthhome* and the reason would be that *birthhouse* is also used as a term in Egyptology.

[In Egyptology, *birthhouse* or *birth house (mammisi)* means the small temples, attached to the main temples of the Ptolemaic and Roman Period. There the god of the main temple was born, or if the main temple was dedicated to a goddess it was where she bore her children. http://buffaloah.com/a/virtual/egypt/edfu/birth/ ]

Example usages from Google Books:

> For instance, there was a steady, but secret flow of tourists visiting Hitler's **birthhouse**; the tourists would usually ask youngsters like myself how to get there, as they were embarrassed to ask adults.
>
> [Strangers at Home and Abroad: Recollections of Austrian Jews who Escaped Hitler *edited by Adolf Wimmer* - 2000]
>
> ---
>
> In “The Jolly Corner,” Spencer Brydon, age fifty-six, comes back to his native New York after a European absence of thirty-three years and is irresistibly drawn to revisit and explore his own **birthhouse**, still standing on “the jolly corner.
>
> [The Turn of the Screw and Other Short Fiction *By Henry James* - 2008]
>
> ---
>
> I walked on Liberty Avenue past my **birthhome** and the playground where my mother used to carefully push the children's swing while I screamed with delight.
>
> [Was That Me?: Turning Points in My Life *By Michael Bivona* - 2010]

Comment: birthhouse is just plain weird. Ok, in anthropology, etc. Sounds like Coming of Age in Samoa. :)